# solving the equation $\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{2}=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the equation :
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{x}+\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{2}=\sqrt{x}$$
this is what I did :
$$\frac{(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}}{2x}=\sqrt{x}$$
$$(x+2)\sqrt{x+2}=2x\sqrt{x}$$
$$(x+2)^{3/2}=2x^{3/2}$$
$$(x+2)^3=4x^3$$
$$x+2=\sqrt[3]{4}x$$
$$x=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{4}-1}$$
I want to be sure if what I did was correct or not, and I am looking for an other methode.

Comment: Seems okay to me.

Comment: [[1]] Plug in the $x$ value in the given Equation to verify that. [[2]] In real number Case , this is okay , whereas in Complex number Case , there may be at least 2 more Solutions. [[3]] When eliminating the cubes , there may be $(\sqrt[3]{1})$ involved , which will then give 2 more Solutions.

Comment: It is quite trivial but you should also verify that the solution found is in the domain, which basically is $x>0$.